# Replace a string after a certain line

Tags: sed

I would like to replace the string "edit TRIES 2" by "edit TRIES 3" after a line that contains the string "task Listen"

```
  task Listen
    edit TRIES 2
```

How can I do it with sed ? The string "edit TRIES 2" appears several times in the file, so I cannot make a simple sed replacement, because I would like to replace that particular line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply

```
sed '/task Listen/{n; s/edit TRIES 2/edit TRIES 3/}' file
```

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
    edit TRIES 2
    edit TRIES 2
  task Listen
    edit TRIES 2
    edit TRIES 2
```

then

```
$ sed '/task Listen/{n; s/edit TRIES 2/edit TRIES 3/}' file
    edit TRIES 2
    edit TRIES 2
  task Listen
    edit TRIES 3
    edit TRIES 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This suggestion solves my problem.

Comment: @Vanda, If the answer helped, you might consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side.

Comment: What does n; do?

Comment: @JigarFaria `n` skips to the **n**ext line - see [sed: Often-Used Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands)

Answer (score 1):

Or with the scriptable editor `ed`: search for the line containing "task Listen", go one beyond it, and replace any "edit TRIES 2" with "edit TRIES 3":

```
printf '%s\n' '/task Listen/+1 s/edit TRIES 2/edit TRIES 3/' 'wq' | ed -s file
```

The `printf` sends two newline-separated commands to `ed` (who is told to suppress diagnostics with `-s`):

1. `/task Listen/+1` -- on the following the one that matches "task Listen",
2. `s/edit TRIES 2/edit TRIES 3/` -- replace any "edit TRIES 2" with "edit TRIES 3"

If the line following "task Listen" does *not* contain "edit TRIES 2", `ed` will exit unsuccessfully (and not change the file).

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:

```
sed -E 'N;s/([[:blank:]]*task Listen\n[[:blank:]]*edit TRIES )[0-9]*)/\13/' file
```

---

Use extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E
```

---

Use the command `N` (new line)

```
'N;
```

---

Match and capture the two lines, either if the beginning are spaces or tabs, in any repetition:

```
([[:blank:]]*task Listen\n[[:blank:]]*edit TRIES )[0-9]*
```

---

Replace the string with the captured pattern and the desired string, in this case `3`:

```
/\13/
```

Comment: The `[0-9]*` at the end is not that relevant, but I leave to match the *exact* pattern.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I totally missed the `N` command. However, you should use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[ \t]` as most `sed` implementations would match space, backslash and the character `t` otherwise.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, I always do it. So far it works, but I'm listening to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The following sed scripts are based on the idea that a line containing zero-or-more spaces and the string "task Listen" defines the beginning of a block of text that you want to edit, and that the block continues until the next "task" or the end of the file (whichever comes first).

It works in cases where the 'edit TRIES 2' line may not immediately follow the `task Listen` line, but could be **anywhere** within the `task Listen` block.

It will also cope with variations in the number of spaces within the `edit TRIES 2` line.

```
sed -E -e '/^ *task Listen/,/^ *task/ {s/edit +TRIES +2 *$/edit TRIES 3/}'
```

Extended regular expressions are enabled (with `-E`) so we can use `+` (1-or-more) without needing to escape it with a backslash.  Also used for alternation `(task|xyz)` without backslash uglification in the second example.

The `*$` at the end of the search regex ensures that it will only match 2 and not some other number beginning with 2.

For example, if given this as input:

```
$ cat input.txt 
  task something
    edit TRIES 2
  task Listen
    foo
    bar
    edit TRIES 25
    edit TRIES 2
  task somethingelse
    edit TRIES 2
```

It will produce the following output:

```
$ sed -E -e '/^ *task Listen/,/^ *task/ {s/edit +TRIES +2 *$/edit TRIES 3/1}' input.txt 
  task something
    edit TRIES 2
  task Listen
    foo
    bar
    edit TRIES 25
    edit TRIES 3
  task somethingelse
    edit TRIES 2
```

Note that it a) didn't change the TRIES 2 to TRIES 3 in either the preceding or following task block and b) did change TRIES 2 **wherever** it appeared in the "task Listen" block.  NOTE: if "edit TRIES 2" occurs more than once in that block, **all** occurrences will be changed.

If the "task Listen" block is, or might be, terminated by something other than a line beginning with zero-or-more spaces and the word "task", you can change the second address to suit.  e.g. if the block could end with either a new task block or an "xyz" block:

```
sed -E -e '/^ *task Listen/,/^ *(task|xyz)/ {s/edit +TRIES +2 *$/edit TRIES 3/1}'
```

To make either of the above sed commands actually change the input file rather than just the output stream, use sed's `-i` option.

Finally, if the input text might contain spaces and/or tabsinstead of just spaces, character you can use the `[[:blank:]]` character class to match them.  e.g.

```
 sed -E -e '/^[[:blank:]]*task Listen/,/^[[:blank:]]*task/ {
   s/edit[[:blank:]]+TRIES[[:blank:]]+2[[:blank:]]*$/edit TRIES 3/}'
```

or, if your version of sed supports perl-compatible regular expressions (e.g. GNU sed):

```
sed -E -e '/^\s*task Listen/,/^\s*task/ {s/edit\s+TRIES\s+2\s*$/edit TRIES 3/}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried with Below command and it worked fine

command

```
sed -n '/task Listen/,+1p' filename| sed "s/edit TRIES 2/edit TRIES 3/g"
```

output

```
task Listen
    edit TRIES 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would remove all lines before "task Listen" as well as all lines from +1 onward.